# Automatically fill auth code for Google's OAuth for devices API

Tags: authentication, google-oauth

I have a console application that uses Google's OAuth for devices workflow to authenticate users using their Google accounts (see: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices).

During the authentication process, the user is required to visit `https://www.google.com/device` and copy-paste a code printed by my app.

Is it possible to include the code as part of the auth url such that the code will already be filled in, and the user only has to click on  to authenticate (I'm thinking on opening a browser window programatically)?

Looking for an option like `https://www.google.com/device?code=ABCD-EFGH`